# Post JSON data in a page, from an URL (dynamic data)

Tags: javascript, json, api, curl

I'm trying to post some mailing campaign statistics in a webpage on a website I'm building with Wordpress. I need the statistics to update on their own as data changes, so instead of parsing a JSON string directly I want to use an URL so the data is continually being fetched from the Mailify (mailing service I'm using) server.

I have some Pascal programming experience but I'm new to javascript and I've been struggling a lot with this particular problem. Because I'm getting desperate, I figured I'd try asking for help.

I've figured out how to request the data from the URL (although I forgot how I did it last time and rn I'm not able to get past the pop-up that requests the credentials), and also how to post on the page using JS, which would be something basic. But I can't figure out how to fetch the data from JSON in real time. I've seen so many different examples but they're all a little different and not really similar to this situation.

Some useful data:

**API Key:** 8RdZ1SkxTeWGlk2T049KOw
**Account ID:** 5c7650c911ce626a6371c1b5
**Mailing campaign ID:** TZi4oEiSRDCqciu-vGV98A
**JSON URL:** https://mailifyapis.com/v1/reports/TZi4oEiSRDCqciu-vGV98A
**JSON URL I'm using to try and include the key and ID:** https://mailifyapis.com/v1/reports/TZi4oEiSRDCqciu-vGV98A&accountId=5c7650c911ce626a6371c1b5&apiKey=8RdZ1SkxTeWGlk2T049KOw (It's still giving me a pop-up)

This is the Mailify documentation page: http://developers.sarbacane.com/#statistiques  (have to translate with Google, they have no translation of their own)

I've tried understanding how curl works but I have to install some stuff and I thought I could get around the problem without it.

Here's what I have tried (I've just been probing the syntax, mostly):

```
<script>
<p id="demo"></p>

var text = 'https://mailifyapis.com/v1/reports/TZi4oEiSRDCqciu-vGV98A&accountId=%225c7650c911ce626a6371c1b5%22&apiKey=%22w_S31uj2RIGHVENnRbD4xw%22';
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
obj.opens = eval("(" + obj.clicks + ")");

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.opens + ", " + obj.clicks();

</script>
```

I realize it doesn't work like this but that was my last attempt. I can't figure out what I should be doing.

Comment: You should provide some code, and tell us exactly what you did so far. Please improve your question

Comment: Probably the best approach is to grab the data with something like jQuery.ajax or fetch, then JSON.parse the response body and access whatever pieces you need in the usual way. (e.g., parsedBody.someStatistic or parsedBody["someStatistic"]), and update the innerHTML of the relevant elements. You'll most likely want to make requests on a regular basis, e.g. every second. Can you show us the code you used to grab?

Comment: @R.Davidson I've updated the post. Doesn't fetch require you to install something on the client side? What you're saying makes sense as an algorithm in my head, but I'm not sure how to do it. How do I handle the URL, exactly? The rest I think I can figure it out. Thanks! I've been at it the whole Sunday.

Comment: @AuRuM Yeah, fetch("http://yoururl.example.com") is pretty much your missing link here. Check out this code example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch  This isn't a complete answer though, since you'll still have to figure out what you did to get past that login page before.

Comment: @R.Davidson Thanks!